# converting import json to work with array formula in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the IMPORTJSON function to lookup shipping status on my google sheet. However it's not designed to work with Arrayformula so I have to apply it to every cell - a big problem with form entries.

```js
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  
  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "";  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the samples before and after the completed script is run?

Comment: I think the OPs question is 'how can I apply this formula to each new form submission since an array formula can't be used to copy it down to each new submission'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think you are asking how to apply the custom formula to each new form submission since you can't use an array formula to copy the formula down.

If this is the case you can use an installed onFormSubmit trigger and apply the formula using R[1]C[1] notation to each new submission.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){  
 var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 var row = e.range.getRow();
 var range = sheet.getRange(row,--column number--);
     range.setFormula('=IMPORTJSON(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-- Column offset of URL--]",0),INDIRECT("R[0]C[--Column offset of xpath--]",0))');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [my PR](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/pull/211) fixes the case where ArrayFormula iterates over URLs for ImportJSON. For example:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BTCUSDT | ETHBTC |
| 3 | BTCRUB | ETHRUB |
| 4 | USDTRUB | ETHUSDT |

```
=arrayformula(IMPORTJSON("https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol="&A2:B4&"", "/symbol,/price",))
```